# What does the "Detected package downgrade" warning mean?

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

When I run `dotnet restore` (or run package restore in Visual Studio), I see warnings like this:

> - /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): warning : Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design from 1.1.1 to 1.0.3  [/Users/markamery/somesolution/SomeSolution.sln]
> - /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): warning :  SomeProject (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (>= 1.1.0) -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (>= 1.1.1)  [/Users/markamery/somesolution/SomeSolution.sln]
> - /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): warning :  SomeProject (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (>= 1.0.3) [/Users/markamery/somesolution/SomeSolution.sln]

I'm struggling to parse the meaning of the warning above. Various things are unclear to me:

- What is a "package downgrade", in this context?
- What causes a "package downgrade" to happen?
- What do the lines below the *"Detected package downgrade"* mean? In particular, what do the arrows (`->`) between packages there convey?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case your dependency graph references two version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`. This is indicated by the lines containing `->`:

After the first line, it shows that your project references `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` version `1.1.0`, which was resolved to a package that in turn references `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` at version `1.1.1`.

Then it is shown that your package directly references `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` at `1.0.3`.

The [NuGet documentation for dependency resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#dependency-resolution-rules) states a rule that will apply in this case:

> **Nearest wins**
>
> When the package graph for an application contains
>   different versions of the same package, the package that's closest to
>   the application in the graph is used and others are ignored. This
>   allows an application to override any particular package version in
>   the dependency graph.

This rule applies here since your app directly references a different version of the package than another dependency. Since this version is lower, NuGet emits a warning to alert you, since the other dependency might expect some functionality that is not present in a lower version. The documentation also includes a warning about this:

> The Nearest Wins rule can result in a downgrade of the package
>   version, thus potentially breaking other dependencies in the graph.
>   Hence this rule is applied with a warning to alert the user.

Comment: What to do if I'm in a situation where the downgrade breaks another package, but removing the downgrade breaks the package that needs the downgrade? Out of luck? I guess that the package that needs the downgrade, needs to be fixed in order to work with the newer version of the dependency?

Comment: If there is a breaking change between the two versions has occurred then yes, you're out of luck. One of the packages needs fixing or you'll need to use lower versions of all packages involved if possible.

Comment: @MartinUllrich I'm really struggling to understand how the `Nearest Win` rule applies to situations where both of the version-constraints are right-side unbounded.  In the OP's example what is preventing `NuGet` from selecting `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.1.1.1` as it satisfies both constraints `>= 1.0.3` and `>=1.1.1` ?  This is especially relevant as I've seen `package downgraded` build-breaking errors rather than just warnings.

Comment: Yes these are build breaking now. NuGet doesn't consider multiple constraints to resolve packages. If you reference a package directly from a project, it will choose the version that satisfies what the project wants and then if another dependency references a higher version, it will give a downgrade errror